# Запись словаря с кирилицей в csv файл ведёт к мусору

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, unicode, csv

Как осуществить нормальную запись кириллицы в файл?
Код программы (Python 3.5):

```
import csv 
parsing_data = [{'phrase': 'пс4', 'num': '90152', 'link': '/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814'}] 
output_file = open("pr1.csv", "w") 
wrtr = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=["phrase", "num", "link"]) 
wrtr.writerow(parsing_data)
```

содержание файла:

> РїСЃ4 90152   /#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814

Comment: @jfs собственно ответ получается пустым
 > b''
думаю в utf-8, я работаю в ubuntu, установил exel через play on linux, и собственно открыв созданный файл вижу такой результат.

Comment: @jfs вот скрин [ссылка](http://savepic.ru/12275123.png)

Comment: @jfs да, считывает верно, получается ошибка в кодировке самого экселя. Не сталкивались с подобной проблемой? как решать? пробовал открывать файл в utf-8, также пробовал перекодировать отдельно текст код .encode('utf-8')
результат тот же.

Answer (score 1):

[Кракозя́бры](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) `РїСЃ4` вместо `пс4` в поле `phrase` происходят из разности набора символов в кодировках `Windows-1251` и  `UTF-8` (`CHCP 65001`). Эксел предполагает `Windows-1251` по умолчанию.

Вероятно, у меня установенная отличная версия Питона но, несмотря на это, следующий снимок экрана выявляет эты кракозя́бры

```
==> python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import csv
>>> parsing_data = [{'phrase': 'пс4', 'num': '90152', 'link': '/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814'}]
>>> output_file = open("pr1.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8')
>>> wrtr = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=["phrase", "num", "link"])
>>> wrtr.writeheader()
>>> wrtr.writerow(parsing_data[0])
36
>>> ^Z


==> type pr1.csv
phrase,num,link
РїСЃ4,90152,/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814

==> chcp
Active code page: 1251

==> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

==> type pr1.csv
phrase,num,link
пс4,90152,/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814

==>
```